# PHP - Keep session up when database information is changed

Tags: php, session

When a user logs into my website a session is created with their "user id". When they want to go change their account information they can click the button and they will be redirected to the "developer_infoupdater.php" file. But every time they change their information, the session ends and they are logged out. I want them to stay logged in after they change their information. I believe the problem is on the "developerUpload.php" file because i am checking if their information is current and if not redirect them to the logout page. And when i changed the destination from logout to a different file, it went to the file that i changed it to.  So what I want is for the user to stay logged in after they update their account information. Here is my code

Developer Upload file

```
<?php
session_start();

 try{

    // new php data object 
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=magicsever', 'root', '');
    //ATTR_ERRMODE set to exception
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}catch(PDOException $e){
     die("There was an error connecting to the database");   

}

//Check if TOKEN used to log in, is actually there
$token = $_SESSION['token'];
$stmtToken = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM token_table WHERE token = :token");
$stmtToken->execute(array(':token'=>$token));
if($rowToken = !$stmtToken->fetch()){

    setcookie("id", "", time() - 60*60);
    $_COOKIE['id'] = "";
    header("Location: developerSignup.php");
    exit;
}

//Check if information is still in there has changed
$userid = $_SESSION['id'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$fullname = $_SESSION['fullname'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];


$stmtChecker = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM generalusersdata WHERE user_id= :userid AND fullname = :fullname AND username = :username AND email = :email");

$stmtChecker->execute(array(':userid'=>$userid, ':fullname'=>$fullname, ':username'=>$username, ':email'=>$email));

if(!$resultChecker = $stmtChecker->fetch()){

    setcookie("id", "", time() - 60*60);
    $_COOKIE['id'] = "";
    header("Location: developerLogin.php");
    exit;

}

if(!password_verify($password, $resultChecker['password'])){

    setcookie("id", "", time() - 60*60);
    $_COOKIE['id'] = "";
    header("Location: developerLogin.php");
    exit;

}

if(isset($_COOKIE['id'])){

    if(isset($_POST['changeSettings'])){

        $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $userid;
        $_SESSION['came_from_upload'] = true;
        header("Location: developer_infoupdater.php");
        exit;

    }
}
```

info update file

```
<?php

session_start();

 if(empty($_FILES) && empty($_POST) && isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post'){ //catch file overload error...
        $postMax = ini_get('post_max_size'); //grab the size limits...
        echo "<p style=\"color: #F00;\">\nPlease note files larger than {$postMax} will result in this error!</p>"; // echo out error and solutions...
        return $postMax;
    }

if(isset($_COOKIE['id'])){

    if($_SESSION['came_from_upload'] != true){

        setcookie("id", "", time() - 60*60);
        $_COOKIE['id'] = "";
        header("Location: developerLogin.php");
        exit;


    }
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =="POST"){
         $token = $_SESSION['token'];
        $userid = $_SESSION['id'];
        $fullname = addslashes(trim($_POST['fullname']));
        $username = addslashes(trim($_POST['username']));
        $email = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
        $password = addslashes(trim($_POST['password']));
        $storePassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));


        try{

        // new php data object 
        $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=magicsever', 'root', '');
        //ATTR_ERRMODE set to exception
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        }catch(PDOException $e){
             die("There was an error connecting to the database");   

        }


        $stmtChecker = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM generalusersdata WHERE user_id = :userid");
        $stmtChecker->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmtChecker->execute();
        if($result = !$stmtChecker->fetch()){

            setcookie("id", "", time() - 60*60);
            $_COOKIE['id'] = "";
            header("Location: developerLogin.php");
            exit;
        }


        if(!empty($fullname)){

            $stmtFullname = $handler->prepare("UPDATE generalusersdata SET fullname = :fullname WHERE user_id = :userid");
            $stmtFullname->bindParam(':fullname', $fullname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmtFullname->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmtFullname->execute();
        }

        if(!empty($username)){

            $stmtCheckerUsername = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM generalusersdata WHERE username = :username");
            $stmtCheckerUsername->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmtCheckerUsername->execute();
            if($resultCheckerUsername = $stmtCheckerUsername->fetch()){

                die("Username Already in use! Please try again");
            }

            $stmtUsername = $handler->prepare("UPDATE generalusersdata SET username = :username WHERE user_id = :userid");
            $stmtUsername->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmtUsername->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmtUsername->execute();

        }

        if(!empty($email)){

            if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false){

            die ("Email is Not Valid!");
        }

            $stmtCheckerEmail = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM generalusersdata WHERE email = :email");
            $stmtCheckerEmail->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmtCheckerEmail->execute();
            if($resultCheckerEmail = $stmtCheckerEmail->fetch()){

                die("Email Already in use! Please try again");
            }

            $stmtEmail = $handler->prepare("UPDATE generalusersdata SET email = :email WHERE user_id = :userid");
            $stmtEmail->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmtEmail->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmtEmail->execute();

        }

        if(!empty($password)){

            if(strlen($password) < 6){

            die ("Password has to be GREATER than 6 characters!");

        }

            //Check if password has atleast ONE Uppercase, One Lowercase and a number
            if(!preg_match("(^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+$)",$password)){

                    echo 'Password needs to be at least ONE uppercase, ONE lowercase, and a number!';
                    exit;
                }

            $stmtPassword = $handler->prepare("UPDATE generalusersdata SET password = :password WHERE user_id = :userid");
            $stmtPassword->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmtPassword->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmtPassword->execute();

        }



        if($_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){

            $file_tmp = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
         //keep only A-Z and 0-9 and everything else KILL
        $file_name = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\.]/", "_", strtolower($_FILES['file']['name']));
         $file_name = strtotime("now")."_".$file_name;
            $mime = mime_content_type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            if(strstr($mime, "video/")){

                die("Please note that this file is NOT an image... Please select an image for your Profile Picture");
            }else if(strstr($mime, "image/")){

            $allowedTypes = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG);
            $detectedType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            if($extensionCheck = !in_array($detectedType, $allowedTypes)){

                die("Failed to upload image; the format is not supported");
            }

             $dir = "devFiles/";

            $uploadedFile = $dir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

             if(is_dir($dir)==false){

                 mkdir($dir, 0700);
             }

             if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadedFile)){

                 die("There was an error moving the file... Please try again later!");
             }

            $stmtFile = $handler->prepare("UPDATE generalusersdata SET profile_image = :file_name, file_tmp = :file_tmp WHERE user_id = :userid");

            $stmtFile->bindParam(':file_name', $file_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmtFile->bindParam(':file_tmp', $file_tmp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmtFile->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmtFile->execute();
            }

        }

        $_SESSION['id'] = $userid;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
        header("Location: developerUpload.php");
        exit;

    }



}else{

    header("Location: developerLogin.php");
    exit;
}





?>
```

Comment: Don't store the data that is subject to change in a session, instead, store the ID and every time you need the data you can fetch it using the ID stored in the session.

Comment: the user id ? it can't change though

Comment: Yes that's the point

Comment: I am so sorry, i really don't understand if you're talking about "userid" or ID in general. Like store the userid as a session? cause thats what i did. I have it with "$_SESSION['id'] = $userid"

Comment: My bad, I didn't explain, my point is, don't store data that is changeable in a session (names, emails...), you can store the primary key in the session and then whenever you need data you can fetch it using the primary key stored in the session.

Comment: fetch it using primary key? so basically use prepared statements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed when changing your user information it doesn't match what was previously cached in the session ( this is logical ).   Seems to me you have 2 choices.

Update session data when making edits ( hard to maintain )

Check only the primary key of the user (this is what i would do)

```
$userid = $_SESSION['id'];
/*  Nuke this stuff
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$fullname = $_SESSION['fullname'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];  // I wouldn't persist the password, what do we need it for after login,
*/

//Look up the user by ID only
$stmtChecker = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM generalusersdata WHERE user_id= :userid");

$stmtChecker->execute(array(':userid'=>$userid));

if(!$resultChecker = $stmtChecker->fetch()){
    setcookie("id", "", time() - 60*60);
    $_COOKIE['id'] = "";
    header("Location: developerLogin.php");
    exit;
}else{
    //if a user with this ID exists update session data.
    $_SESSION['username'] = $resultChecker['username'];
    $_SESSION['fullname'] = $resultChecker['fullname'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $resultChecker['email'];
}
```

Comment: Oh i see so we set the "username etc" to a session then we can use it later and set it to a variable ? Like i will need "username" so after creating the session, do i just create the variable "$username"?

Comment: You can just access it right from the session `$_SESSION['username'] ` if you need it in another file, or you could set it to a variable, depends on the downstream code flow.

Comment: The point is, that the Primary Key, the user ID wont change when making edits.  It is best to not look the user up by things like username and email if you already know their ID.  Also just performance wise, ID should be set to Primary key ( indexed ), as an INT and you wont get a faster lookup then that.

Comment: You mean set it as "Primary Key" in the database?

Comment: I assumed the ID field was a auto increment primary key type for the field that's typical ...